# Backbone.js load XML to Backbone.Model and show it on view

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm trying to make some non standard backbone app, with requery.js structure under the hub
I load data from XML inside my collection, and try to show it on view page.

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/products'
], function($, _, Backbone, ProductsModel){
  var ProductsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ProductsModel,
    url: "Labels.xml",
    parse: function(data) {
    var parsed=[];
    $(data).find('item').each(function (index) {
        var productNode = $(this).attr('nodeID');
        var productNodeValue = $(this).text();
        parsed.push({ title: productNode, value: productNodeValue });
    });
    return parsed;
},

fetch: function(options) {
    options || (options = {});
    options.dataType="xml";
    Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
},
initialize: function(){
}

  });

  return ProductsCollection;
});
```

this is collection and so far it's filled up with data from XML, but I would like to show it on page..
view looks like this

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  // Pull in the Collection module from above
  'collections/products',
  'text!templates/products/main.html'

 ], function($, _, Backbone, ProductsCollection, productsListTemplate){
  var productsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#page"),
    render: function(){
      var data = {
        productDetails: this.collection,
        _: _ 
      };
      var compiledTemplate = _.template( productsListTemplate, data );
      this.$el.html( compiledTemplate ); 
    },  
    initialize: function(){
      this.collection = new ProductsCollection();
      this.collection = this.collection.fetch();
    }
  });
   return productsListView;
});
```

and on page I try to show it like

```
<ul>
  <% _.each(productDetails, function(project){ %>
   <li><%= product.get("title") %> - <%= product.get("value") %></li> 
  <% }); %>
</ul>
```

but I always get error _each is not well formatted.
Main idea is to load labels, and button events from XML and show it up on page..

Comment: What is the exact error message that you're getting? That sort of thing should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/n2vMc/ You could just say `productDetails.each(function(project) { ... })` anyway: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods

Comment: I get
Error: not well-formed
Source File: file:///templates/products/main.html
Line: 3, Column: 4
Source Code:
  <% _.each(productDetails, function(project){ %>

Comment: same is if I put just productDetails.each(function(project) { ... })

Comment: That error would suggest that someone is trying to treat your template as `text/html` when it isn't. Change the type to `type="text/x-underscore"` if you're using a `<script>` for your template or rename the file to `main.txt` if the template is the whole file.

Comment: I include it like <script data-main="js/main" src="./js/libs/require/require.js"></script> and template is just an html file with those <ul> / each logic, tried to changed it to txt but it leads me to URI problem, otherwise still have same issue

Comment: I figured this out problem was in fact that my view has been rendered before data fetch and I solve it as like this   initialize : function() {
   this.collection = new ProductsCollection();
   var self = this;
   this.collection.fetch({
       success: function () {
           self.render();
       }
   });
  },

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass to your template  `this.collection.models` not just `this.collection`

```
var data = {
  productDetails: this.collection.models,
  _: _ 
};
```

Because you are using Underscore not Backbone. The Backbone way for looping is

```
Books.each(function(book) {
   book.publish();
});
```

Comment: if I try to add this.collection.models I get error that  this.collection is undefined. Idea is that collection would be filled from data which are returned from XML, and I do fatching under the initialize part in view, and in collection I parse XML and push it to object.

Comment: after few days on it, still have this issue but I just isolate the problem, seems like rendering has been applied before XML data has been retrieved and my object is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still having trouble with this, but there is an error in your code:

`<ul>
  <% _.each(productDetails, function(project){ %>
   <li><%= product.get("title") %> - <%= product.get("value") %></li> 
  <% }); %>
</ul>`

should be:

`<ul>
  <% _.each(productDetails, function(product){ %>
   <li><%= product.get("title") %> - <%= product.get("value") %></li> 
  <% }); %>
</ul>`